# MongoError: attempt to write outside buffer bounds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple node.js code that is trying to fetch the object, populate the field and then update the same object :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, Db = require('mongodb').Db
, Server = require('mongodb').Server
, ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var db = new Db('testing', new Server('localhost', 27017));
db.open(function(err, db){
   var Users = db.collection('users');
   Users.find({code  : {$exists : false} }, {email : 1}, function(err,      users){
   users.forEach(function(user){
       var code = generateCode();
       var userID  = user._id;
       Users.update({ _id :  user._id  }, {$set : {code : code } }, function(err, results){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(results);
       });

   });
});
```

When I try to do an update mongo is throwing:

```
MongoError: attempt to write outside buffer bounds.
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `generateCode()` return?

Comment: a string - 512 chars long.

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example code value that causes the error?

Comment: Sry, I totally forgot about this question, generateCode() function was returning a complex object (with properties and functions inside), that's why mongo could not save it. 

if you want to save a function you have to add it to a special system collection called system.js.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurred when try to save/update document with huge information/illegal type information.

In mongodb, the maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes. Here is [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) for more details.